# "I am (on) every Wednesday in the college"

Tags: prepositions

As far as I remember from my learning, before the name of a day the preposition "**on**" should be there. For example:

> He'll be there **on** Sunday. He was there **on** Sunday.

Then my question if this rule is also valid when the word "every" exists?

For example:

> "I am **on every Wednesday** at the college."

Or should I omit the preposition "on" from it?

Comment: Not in that order. You would say "I am at the college (on) every Wednesday." or "(On) every Wednesday I am at the college." Using *on* in these cases is optional.

Comment: Did you perhaps read something like "It's on every Wednesday evening at 9 p.m."?  The "on" refers to a TV programme being broadcast e.g. TBBT is on CBS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When, if ever, have you seen that particular construction? “I am on every Wednesday…”?

Adverb phrases that express time go either at the beginning or at the end of a sentence.

- ***Yesterday*** I went to college
- *I went to college **yesterday***.

The following is very awkward

- *I **yesterday** went to college* (NO)

Likewise, the time expression "every Wednesday", is no different

- *Every Wednesday* I am at college
- I go to college *every Wednesday*.

The preposition *on* is used ***before days of the week, before specific parts of the day and for dates***.

- **On** Wednesdays, I go to college
- The graduation ceremony is **on** May 14th, and the commencement speech by Tom Smith will begin **on** Friday morning at 10.30.

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm

There is, however, one usage of “on every + [day]” that sounds idiomatic. When we mention the days and times of TV or radio shows. For example,

> - *[It's on every Monday night](http://news.bbc.co.uk/local/stoke/hi/tv_and_radio/newsid_8430000/8430474.stm) 7-9pm on BBC Radio Stoke and on the BBC iPlayer*.
> - When To Listen: NOW! [It’s on every Monday](http://www.wrbh.org/wrbh-blog-6-books-to-look-forward-to-this-spring/) through Friday at 11AM (and again at 9:30PM) during our Best Selling Fiction program and read by first-time book reader, Geoff Worden.
> - Spotlight is the show on National Prison Radio which shines a light on those charities and organisations in prison which are there to help you. [It’s on every Monday](https://insidetime.org/informing-find-help/) at 11am, repeated at 5pm.
> - I think afternoon programmes are as good as evening ones and, like I'm out tonight and I know Dallas is on because [it's on every Wednesday](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Nc-HAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=%22it%27s%20on%20every%20Wednesday%22&source=bl&ots=MXhKL7WPNP&sig=WBJVCOaT-y0DEsvDQQuWHyfX340&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv9Ynq06XbAhWoxFQKHdoGCIIQ6AEIOzAH#v=onepage&q=%22it's%20on%20every%20Wednesday%22&f=false), so I shall ask him ...

Here, the preposition "on" refers to  *being broadcast by (a radio or television channel)* e.g. ‘[a new twelve-part TV series on Channel 4](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on#h46915568349140)’, *‘The show will be broadcast **on** CBS **on** December 26th.’*

Comment: Please, note if that it is optional to add the preposition "on" or you don't agree with it.

Comment: @subtle_sibling  "I am on every Wednesday at the college" sounds more like you're doing a TV, theatre or radio show that is broadcast or shown in college. In your cited examples, it is inappropriate, I think I made that quite clear.